# unexpected compilation error in a function call (C++)

Tags: c++, function, codeblocks, boost-tokenizer

I have a template function `makeMatrix()`, code is:

```
template<size_t N>
void makeMatrix(string dataFilePath, int adjcMatrix[N][N])
{
  fstreamExtension fe("adj.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);
  string s;
  vector<int> temp;
  int i = 0;

  while(!fe.eof())
  {
      getline(fe, s);
      temp = tokenizeToInt(s, ",\n")); //error: expected ';' before ')' token|

      for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
          adjcMatrix[i][j] = temp[j];

      i += 1;
  }
}
```

fstreamExtension is a class I created and is included in program through header
`#include "fstreamExtension.h"`, other included headers are `iostream` `string` and `boost/tokenizer.hpp`.

code for `tokenizeToInt()`:

```
vector<int> tokenizeToInt(string& intString, const char* seperators)
{
   vector<int> intValues;

   boost::char_separator<char> delims(seperators);
   boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(intString, delims);

   for (const auto& t : tokens) {
       intValues.push_back(atoi(t.c_str()));
   }

   return intValues;

}
```

Why it is causing a compilation error in the `makeMatrix()`, the syntax seems correct, I didn't called it in `main()`, was compiling some other code then this error popped up when I started a build.

IDE : codeblocks 16.01, gcc.

Comment: Count your parentheses `(` and `)`.

Comment: It takes longer to type up the question than to find the error.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll refrain from using iostrem::eof in a loop comdition from now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to what the compiler tells you. Often the error is simpler than you think:

```
temp = tokenizeToInt(s, ",\n")); //error: expected ';' before ')' token|
```

An extra right-parenthesis. The compiler error means "I thought you were done with this command, why are you trying to close another parenthesis-pair?"